# Facing this issue with flutter_webview_plugin while running on latest version of Flutter 2.10.3

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutterwebviewplugin

The plugin flutter_webview_plugin uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are a plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
[image]

This issue has already been raised on Github https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/921
but as of now, I am unable to change this library to any other because my project is already in the deployment phase.

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/921#issuecomment-947568187